# iOS: Accessing wsdl service api from iOS client

Tags: ios

I have a web service created through Eclipse. Created a web service method and wsdl for that class. I would like to know how can i access this web service api from my iOS client? For ex: my wsdl file is 'ReceiverClass.wsdl' and 'ReceiverClass.java class contains a method called 'RespondResult(..)'. I know about NSURLConnection, i'm asking how can i point to this url api?

Thank you!

Getsy.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a SOAP framework. There's not one built into iOS, but here's one which was the first hit on Github: https://github.com/priore/SOAPEngine.

Comment: I am asking to access as REST service, not soap service. what should id do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [iPhone Web Services Client](https://github.com/akosma/iPhoneWebServicesClient). Also can refer to these tutorials.

[SOAP Based Web Services Made Easy On The iOS Platform](http://maniacdev.com/2012/01/tool-soap-based-web-services-made-easy-on-ios)

[Working with iOS and SOAP](http://blog.exadel.com/working-with-ios-and-soap/)

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy solution, easiest one is to move away from SOAP.

Meanwhile you can try http://sudzc.com/ or you can write a simple wrapper yourself which will send and receive XML packets.

In example below, I observed the xml packets through "Poster" firefox plugin and made generic methods to make SOAP request. The biggest drawback is that I'm ignoring WSDL and I have to implement each method myself (unlike Java).

```
- (void) requestData:(NSString *) request withParameters:(NSDictionary*)parameters
          soapAction:(NSString*)soapAction serviceName:(NSString *)url
             success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
             failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
{
    NSString *packet = [self formatRequest:request WithParameters:parameters];
    NSData *envelope = [packet dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request1 = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];
    [request1 setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request1 setHTTPBody:envelope];
    [request1 setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation * operation =  [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager] HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request1 success:success failure:failure];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:operation];

}

- (NSString*) formatRequest:(NSString*)request WithParameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
{
    NSMutableString *packet = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [packet appendString:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
     "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">"
     "<soap12:Body>"];

    [packet appendFormat:@"<%@ xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">",request];

    for (NSString *key in parameters) {
        [packet appendFormat:@"<%@>%@</%@>",key,[parameters objectForKey:key],key];
    }

    [packet appendFormat:@"</%@>",request];
    [packet appendString:@"</soap12:Body></soap12:Envelope>"];

    return packet;
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to push one UIImage (NSData) to my server code. How do i  call my web service api, for ex: like this-> NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.x.x:8080/ReceiverClass/RespondResult?filename=myimage"];
    
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];